# Creating a number guessing game that has stages

Tags: javascript, html, css

Create a number guessing game to generate a number between the range of 1 and 2. The game should prompt users for their username.
Set range as function parameter and prompt the player to predict the generated number between the given range. At a correct guess, the game should award the player a point and move them to stage 2 by increasing the range limit value by 1, e.g. range is from 1 and 3 for stage 2 and so on.

I created it but to flow from one level to another is the problem

Comment: will the random range include decimal numbers like ```1.3```?

Answer (score 1):

This is a working solution. Feel free to comment with any questions.

```js
let rangeTracker = [1, 2]
let totalPointsTracker = [0]

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}

document.getElementById('continueBtn').onclick = function() {
  let username = document.getElementById("newUsername").value
  if (username != '') {
    document.querySelector('.usernameCon').style.display = 'none'
    document.querySelector('.userInfo').style.display = 'flex'
    document.querySelector('.gameCon').style.display = 'flex'
    document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = `Hello ${username}, this is stage ${totalPointsTracker[0] + 1}`
    document.getElementById("totalPoints").innerHTML = `Total Points: ${totalPointsTracker[0]}`
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = `Guess a number between ${rangeTracker[0]} and ${rangeTracker[1]}`
  }
}

const randomInt = randomIntFromInterval(rangeTracker[0], rangeTracker[1])

document.getElementById('guessBtn').onclick = function() {
  let userGuess = document.getElementById("userGuess").value
  if (userGuess != '') {
    if (userGuess == randomInt) {
      document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = `Correct!`
      document.getElementById("status").style.color = 'forestgreen'
      const previousMaxRange = rangeTracker[1]
      rangeTracker[1] = previousMaxRange + 1
      const previousTotalPoints = totalPointsTracker[0]
      totalPointsTracker[0] = previousTotalPoints + 1
      success()
    } else {
      document.getElementById("userGuess").value = ''
      document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = `Incorrect, guess again!`
      document.getElementById("status").style.color = 'red'
    }
  } else if (userGuess == '') {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = `Please guess a number!`
    document.getElementById("status").style.color = 'red'
  }
}

function success() {
  let username = document.getElementById("newUsername").value
  document.getElementById("userGuess").value = ''
  document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = `Hello ${username}, this is stage ${totalPointsTracker[0] + 1}`
  document.getElementById("totalPoints").innerHTML = `Total Points: ${totalPointsTracker[0]}`
  document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = `Guess a number between ${rangeTracker[0]} and ${rangeTracker[1]}`
}
```

```css
.usernameCon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.usernameCon label {
  font-size: 26px;
}

.usernameCon #newUsername {
  width: 230px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.usernameCon #continueBtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 130px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.userInfo {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: fit-content;
}

.userInfo #username {
  font-size: 26px;
}

.userInfo #totalPoints {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.gameCon {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.gameCon #title {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.gameCon #status {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.gameCon #userGuess {
  width: 230px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.gameCon #guessBtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 130px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="usernameCon">
  <label>Enter Your Username</label>
  <input id="newUsername" />
  <button id="continueBtn">Continue</buttom>
</div>

<div class="userInfo">
  <label id="username"></label>
  <label id="totalPoints"></label>
</div>

<div class="gameCon">
  <label id="title">Guess a number between 1 and 2</label>
  <label id="status"></label>
  <input id="userGuess" />
  <button id="guessBtn">Guess</button>
</div>
```